# Conditional select in sql query

Tags: sql, case

I am trying to access a field from a table and give different output based on the field content.
If the field has `0` I want to fetch `No` else if `1` or `NULL` I want to fetch `yes`.
It is working well for `0` or `1` but not for `NULL`.

```
Select  distinct(convert(varchar(255),( CASE Field1
                                         WHEN 0 
                                             THEN 'No'
                                         WHEN 1
                                             THEN 'Yes'
                                         WHEN NULL 
                                             THEN 'Yes' 
                                       END ))) AS Field1 FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CASE Field1
WHEN 0 THEN 'No'              
ELSE 'Yes'
END
```

or this:

```
CASE ISNULL(Field1, 1)
WHEN 0 THEN 'No'              
WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     Select  distinct(convert(varchar(255),
     (CASE Field1 WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
      WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'              
      WHEN IS NULL THEN 'Yes'
     END))) as Field1 from Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL(CASE Field1 WHEN 0 THEN 'No' WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes','Yes') AS ..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  distinct(convert(varchar(255),( CASE Field1
     WHEN 0 THEN               
    'No'              
     else 'Yes'  END )))as Field1 from Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  distinct(convert(varchar(255),
    CASE ISNULL(FIELD1, 1)
        WHEN 0 THEN 'No'              
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'                        
    END 
        ))as FIELD1 
        from TABLE1
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you want this:

```
 Select  distinct(convert(varchar(255),( CASE 

     WHEN Field1 =0 THEN               
    'No'              
WHEN Field1=1  THEN              
    'Yes'              
     WHEN Field1 is null THEN 'Yes'              
END )))as Field1 from Table1
```